# How to read html information that is not directly displayed in a link with python?

Tags: python, html, pandas, http

I create a code in python that use the following line to read information and table from a html link to get coordinates from a project.

```
path = https://busquedas.elperuano.pe/normaslegales/otorgan-a-la-empresa-ignis-energy-peru-sac-la-concesion-t-resolucion-ministerial-no-369-2022-minemdm-2113205-1/
df_project = pd.read_html(url_path)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
HTTP Error 308: Permanent Redirect
```

When I checked what happened, I could see that recently the entity that publish this information changed the url to this

```
Link: https://busquedas.elperuano.pe/dispositivo/NL/2113205-1
```

But now, to go to the html it is necessary to do a previous click on "html tab", it is not direct anymore.

Could someone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

When you open Web Developer Tools -> Network tab and click on the `HTML` button, you will see this url: https://busquedas.elperuano.pe/api/visor_html/2113205-1

So, to load the table from this URL:

```py
import pandas as pd

url = "https://busquedas.elperuano.pe/api/visor_html/2113205-1"

df = pd.read_html(url, converters={"NORTE": lambda x: x})[0]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   VÉRTICE         ESTE         NORTE
0       V1  497189.5165  9434972.1636
1       V2  497299.6423  9434956.6590
2       V3  496507.1663  9431190.4090
3       V4  497477.7193  9431030.7381
4       V5  498072.6989  9435019.8582
5       V6  501753.3724  9434497.1904
6       V7  504845.4803  9434254.9008
7       V8  504709.3881  9433728.3335
8       V9  505014.6188  9433701.3933
9      V10  505142.5750  9434231.2568
10     V11  507145.3583  9434071.8674
11     V12  506896.2186  9430635.7905
12     V13  499740.9567  9430635.7913
13     V14  499740.9541  9420798.4518
14     V15  498420.8770  9421594.0357
15     V16  497737.8273  9421346.2970
16     V17  497329.0275  9420525.3815
17     V18  501599.6644  9417798.5229
18     V19  501562.4543  9417371.3889
19     V20  500608.3662  9417438.5993
20     V21  500294.0109  9417403.4404
21     V22  499820.6634  9418443.1213
22     V23  498024.7188  9418808.2360
23     V24  497498.1970  9419906.2590
24     V25  496048.5679  9419111.8058
25     V26  494720.9939  9421916.0135
26     V27  494353.4392  9423746.1620
27     V28  494571.6651  9423845.5209
28     V29  494090.6163  9427023.3186
29     V30  495077.0506  9429517.1769
```